# GStreamer videotestsrc to RTP

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I'm just trying to get an RTP sample working, but every example I've seen doesn't execute due to missing plugins or incorrect pins.

This seems the most promising, but, although the server and client seem to launch properly and go to "PLAYING", nothing happens:

Server:

```
gst-launch -v videotestsrc ! \
    video/x-raw-rgb, format=\(fourcc\)RGB, width=4, height=4, frame-rate=1/1 ! rtpvrawpay !
    udpsink host=127.0.0.1
```

Server output:

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)RGB, depth=(string)8, width=(string)4, height=(string)4, colorimetry=(string)SMPTE240M, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)3779397700, clock-base=(uint)1161131286, seqnum-base=(uint)43390
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
```

Client:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)RGB, depth=(string)8, width=(string)4, height=(string)4, colorimetry=(string)SMPTE240M, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)3779397700, clock-base=(uint)1161131286, seqnum-base=(uint)43390" ! rtpvrawdepay ! xvimagesink
```

Client output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpVRawDepay:rtpvrawdepay0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw-rgb, width=(int)4, height=(int)4, format=(fourcc)0x00000000, framerate=(fraction)0/1, endianness=(int)4321, red_mask=(int)16711680, green_mask=(int)65280, blue_mask=(int)255, bpp=(int)24, depth=(int)24
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpVRawDepay:rtpvrawdepay0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)RGB, depth=(string)8, width=(string)4, height=(string)4, colorimetry=(string)SMPTE240M, ssrc=(uint)3779397700, clock-base=(uint)1161131286, seqnum-base=(uint)43390
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These work:

Server:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v \
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin1 \
videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! rtpbin1.send_rtp_sink_0 \
rtpbin1.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5011 \
rtpbin1.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5012 \
udpsrc port=5013 ! rtpbin1.recv_rtcp_sink_0
```

Client:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v \
videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink sync=false async=false \
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin1 \
udpsrc port=5011 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0LAFdkBQfsBEAAAAwAXc1lAAPFi5IAA\\,aMuMsg\\=\\=\", ssrc=(uint)595281375, payload=(int)96, clock-base=(uint)3105254905, seqnum-base=(uint)59233" ! rtpbin1.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin1. ! rtph264depay ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix. \
udpsrc port=5012 ! rtpbin1.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
rtpbin1.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5013 host=127.0.0.1
```